# Обработка ссылок ТЕГА {a} на PHP

Tags: ссылки, php, парсер

Значит, задача такая, я на PHP получаю страницу, потом эту страницу распарсиваю, использую `simple_html_dom.php` Может есть что получше? Подскажите.

Вот, получаю ссылки на странице. Но, есть одно но! Ссылки бывают такие (чисто значение из параметра href):

> `http://site/page.php - ваще зачет такая ссылка и нужна
> /newpage.php - 
> mypage.html
> ./superpage.php
> ../trololo.php`

Как эти относительные страницы привязать или превратить в абсолютные? Моя функция:

```
function get_href($url, $parent) {
    global $root, $root_url; // урл сайта

    $url = preg_replace('{#.*?$}i','',$url); // убираем #....

    if (!preg_match('{^(http://|https://|ftp://)}i',$url)) {
        // если совпадает страница с корнем с урлом сайта
        if ($parent == $root_url) $p = pathinfo( $parent . '1' );
        else $p = pathinfo($parent);

        if ($url{0} == '/') {
            $url = $p['dirname']. $url;
        } else {
            $url = $p['dirname'].'/'.$url;
        }
        return $url;
}
```

Но она не справляется с `../ ./`, а с `/page` и `page` вроде норм.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создал вот такую функцию, справляется со всеми требованиями

```
function get_href($url, $parent, &$type) {
    // global $alternative 
    $type = 0; // по умолчанию внутренняя
    // $root = parse_url($this->site->root);
    // удалить #.....
    $url = preg_replace('{#.*?$}i','',$url);
    // удалить sid!
    $url = preg_replace('{[\?\&]sid\=[a-z0-9]+$}i','',$url);
    $url = preg_replace('{(&amp;|&)sid\=[a-z0-9]+$}i','',$url);

    $url = preg_replace('{#.*?$}i','',$url);
    // удалить параметры из урла родителя
    $parent = preg_replace('{\?.*?$}i','',$parent);

    $url = str_ireplace($this->site->alt, $this->site->domen, $url);

    if (!preg_match('{^(http://|https://|ftp://)}i',$url)) {

        // $p = parse_url($parent);
        if ($parent == $this->site->root_url) $p = pathinfo( $parent . '1' );
        else $p = pathinfo($parent);
        // var_dump(, $parent, $p); die;

        if ($url{0} == '/') {
            return $url ;
        } else if ($url{0} == '.' AND $url{1} == '/') {
            return substr($url, 1);
        } else {
            // предыдущий / до него надо обрезать строку
            $p = $this->get_parent($parent);
            debug($url, $parent, $p, $p . $url );
            return $p . $url;
        }

        return $url;

    }

    $u = parse_url($url);
    if ($u['host'] != $this->site->domen) $type = 1; // внешняя
    else return str_ireplace($this->site->root_url,'',$url);
    return $url; 
}
```